# Error al leer archivo .csv

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo .csv pero me tira este mensaje de error, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
df <- read.csv("/home/gustavo/DatosVivos/R/R_proy_y_data_20200827/data/informe_ministerio_202110.csv")
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  string multibyte 1 inválida
```

Si pongo el separador, muestra un error similar:

```
df <- read.csv("/home/gustavo/DatosVivos/R/R_proy_y_data_20200827/data/informe_ministerio_202110.csv", sep = ";")
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  string multibyte 4 inválida
```

Comment: Fíjate cual es el separador. 
Si el error persiste lo mejor es usar la función fread() del paquete data.table.

Comment: @césar, gracias por molestarte en responder. Funcionó! Gracias por el dato.